# htaccess https www. Trailing Slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I having these redirects home page working fine with this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but i have redirects with the rest of the pages

```
http://example.com/kapcsolat
https://www.example.com/kapcsolat
https://www.examplecom/page/
```

i tried this code works fine for all pages

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*?)/?$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

but i got redirects for home page double Trailing Slash :

```
http://example.com
https://www.example.com//
https://www.example.com/
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: The leading slash gets stripped off the URL that RewriteRule matches on, when configured in .htaccess context. So `$1` will simply be empty in this case, and therefor `/$1/` leads to the double slash. You need to handle the request for the root URL separately here.

Comment: what do u mean ! to use 2 codes ?